# how to load a multilayer image in as3, flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Does anybody have idea how to load a multilayer image in as3, flex. and there should be option to change fill colour of each layer. like here on this site, clip art is loaded in layers and color can be specified for each layer

http://opentshirts.org/version1

Comment: It's not a multilayer image, it's multiple layers of vectors.

Comment: hmm, i got the idea, so can we change the color of vector in flex?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [ColorTransform](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html).

```
// some displayobject
var someDisplayObject:DisplayObject = topLayer;

// tint to white 100%
someDisplayObject.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1,1,1,1,255,255,255,0);

// tint to black 100%
someDisplayObject.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1);
```